# Are Alchemy tools expendable or not?

Tags: equipment, burning-wheel

BWGR, p. 254:

> Alchemy is the distillation of materials in order to divine their essence. Also, alchemists can create mixtures of arcane substances to generate a specific effect.
> ...
>
> Tools: Yes. **Expendable.**

Codex, p. 413:

> *This entry is an update of Alchemy that incorporates all of the new applications presented in this book.* Alchemy is the distillation of materials in order to divine their essence. Alchemists may also create mixtures of arcane substances to generate a specific effect. ...
>
> Tools: Yes. **[???]**

I get that Codex Alchemy "is an update", but I'm a little concerned that the skill got more powerful at the same time the tools became permanent (no longer breaking on a Die of Fate roll of 1). I have a power-gamer in the group and need to rein in some of the crazier mechanics, and breakable tools would go a ways to mitigating that.

So is this discrepancy just an oversight, or is the new version of Alchemy intentionally strictly better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Now that alchemy actually does something, fragile Ob 6 tools aren't the best for its intended function.

I should perhaps explain that a little bit. In *BWGR* Alchemy provides some standard Obstacles for distilling the essences of certain classes of substances, but unless I've overlooked something there isn't actually a defined use for any of them -- you can't, for example, incorporate an essence of blood in your sorcerous workings to reduce the Obstacle of casting or anything like that.

As a result, if a purely *BWGR* GM expects or allows the players to use Alchemy to accomplish their goals, they do so at their discretion with full consideration that the process of Alchemy uses fragile Sorcerous-grade tools.

However, in the Codex, Alchemy does have a use exposed to the players: providing raw materials for Enchanting, which is also accomplished by Taxidermy, a skill which uses cheaper Medicinal tools which also don't break. (The costs of tools for different skill categories can be found in the Resources chapter on *BWGR* p. 367.)

If you want to restrict your player from accomplishing things with Enchanting, a better place to look is at the actual Enchanting obstacles, especially as they relate to enchantment duration and targets.